# Merge Excel workbooks including the VBA code

Tags: vba, excel, merge

I found a lot of solutions to merge two Excel workbooks together, but I still did not find a method to merge the VBA code (macros) too.

I tried [Kutools](https://www.extendoffice.com/product/kutools-for-excel.html), which is a very promising tool, but it didn't copied anything. (their website does not advertise that it will copy VBA anyway...)

So there are two XLSM files with few dozen of worksheets, named ranges and macros, and I want to merge the contents of both into a single XLSM file. Probably there will be no name collisions, or if any I can solve it manually, so no automatic renaming needed.

Is there a way to do this apart from manually copying the code in the VBA IDE?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much work you'll save compared to copying and pasting the code, but you can export and import modules.  If you right-click on the module you want to export, you'll see the menu options.  The files are .bas (procedures), .cls (class) or .frm (user forms).  They can then be imported directly.  I haven't been successful in importing a module directly from another .xlsm file.

[image: VBE export import menu options]